# SPO Retrieve Site Properties returns empty or '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' Sensitivity Label in SiteProperties class

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, csom, site-collection, tenant

I'm trying to get all site collections (including it's properties) under a SPO Tenant with below piece of code:

```
            SPOSitePropertiesEnumerable sites;
        List<SiteProperties> allSiteProperties = new List<SiteProperties>();
        using (ClientContext tenantCtx = getTenantContext())
        {

            var tenant = new Tenant(tenantCtx);
            int startIndex = 0;

            do
            {
                sites = tenant.GetSitePropertiesFromSharePoint(Convert.ToString(startIndex), true);
                tenantCtx.Load(sites);
                tenantCtx.ExecuteQuery();

                allSiteProperties.AddRange(sites);

                startIndex = sites.NextStartIndex;

            } while (sites.NextStartIndex > 0);

        }
```

However, I'm getting some of the information as empty or **00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000** (incase of Guid properties) e.g. Sensitivity Label, Sensitivity Label2 that is referencing to the **SiteProperties** class of **Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.TenantAdministration** (using Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM package).

Since, there are around 3 lakhs site collections under a tenant, I'm trying to optimize the code by not querying every site collections to get it's properties.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Some Configuration Manager object properties are relatively inefficient to retrieve. If these properties were retrieved for many instances in a class (as might be done in a query), the response would be considerably delayed. Such properties are considered lazy properties and are not usually retrieved during query operations. However, if these properties are retrieved during a query, they have null or zero values, which might not be the actual value of the property for every instance. Therefore, if you want to get the correct value for lazy properties, you must get each instance individually.

Comment: Getting each instance of site individually will result in poor performance. Will try with powershell if that works.

Comment: You can refer to following document to retrieve sharepoint sensitivity label
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/microsoft-365-docs/blob/public/microsoft-365/compliance/sensitivity-labels-sharepoint-onedrive-files.md

Comment: I am checking to see if the problem has been resolved.